# Make Target _Blank With This Attacment PHP

Tags: wordpress, media, attachment

this php below will print like this http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/imagename.jpg with anchor text 'DOWNLOAD'

```
<?php  

if ( $attachments = get_children( array(  
'post_type' => 'attachment',  
'post_mime_type'=>'image',  
'numberposts' => 1,  
'post_status' => null,  
'post_parent' => $post->ID  
)));
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {  
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, '' , false, true, 'Download');  
}  
?>
```

1.when user clicking this link, how to target in _blank or open in new tab.

2.is possible this short code combine with Javascript to make Force download link? look like bellow.

```
if ( $attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'=>'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
) ) );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);"
        onclick="document.execCommand(\'SaveAs\', true, \'' . get_permalink( $attachment->ID ) . '\');">
        Download This Wallpaper</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant below in my response.

```
array(  
'post_type' => 'attachment',  
'post_mime_type'=>'image',  
'numberposts' => 1,  
'post_status' => null,  
'post_parent' => $post->ID ,
'target' => 'target="_blank"'; 
)
```

See if it works this way.

Comment: Why not try include a target for your array?
array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'=>'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'target' => '_blank'
)
See if it works this way.

Comment: thats not error, but not open in new tab, same as code above.

Comment: At what point are you getting this error? If you run without the line I added, what do you get? Can you read through your get_children() function then edit to fit in the "target" in your array. Okay... then change it to 'target' => 'target="_blank"'; I think it should now be able to print it as target="_blank" and not just as _blank without the target tag added

Comment: your edited code is working too, but i use look like this code, and work too. `echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) . '">Download</a>';` btw, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

amek teh chages and try this

```
 foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);"
    onclick="document.execCommand(\'SaveAs\', true, \'' . get_permalink( $attachment->ID ) . '\');" target="blank">
    Download This Wallpaper</a>';
```

}

hope this will helpt you

Comment: yeh! this open in new tab.. but not downloading image. hoho

Comment: onclick="document.execCommand(\'SaveAs\', true, \'' . get_permalink( $attachment->ID ) . '\'); window.open(this.href);return false;"   replace this with in code